# Past progressive with "always"

Tags: progressive-aspect, intensifying-adverbs

I am a student learning English. I learned in a class that either present or past progressive can be used to express a negative reaction to a situation.
The explanations on the lecture note the professor gave are written as follows:

> The present progressive is often used with *always* to express a negative reaction to a situation.
>
> > He's always calling me "Sweetie." I hate that name.
>
> The past progressive with *always* can also be used to criticize actions we feel are annoying, or which we wish to exaggerate.
>
> > At school, he was always getting into trouble.

I am confused because the explanation about past progressive shows that we use past progressive to criticize actions we *feel* (present) are annoying.

Does the past progressive with *always* reflect the same tense with the present progressive with *always*?

Comment: I don't think the negative connotations are really associated with progressive tense as such - it's more to do with the *semantics* of the word ***always***. Which are the same if not stronger in, say, *He **constantly/continually** calls me "Sweetie", which I hate.* And idiomatically most people wouldn't normally use a continuous form with that example.

Comment: "God is such a gentleman, He's [always opening](https://twitter.com/kelliewellz/status/345517165912391681) doors for me!".

Comment: @Hee: emphasis on *can be used*.

Comment: `In present-day English combinations of the progressive and adverbials of frequency often convey connotations of annoyance or irritation...` See page 19 here: (http://clu.uni.no/icame/ij18/elsness.pdf)

Comment: In American English, "always  X-ing" or "forever X-ing"  often connotes annoyance or irritation. *That dog is always barking.  You're always tracking mud into the house. You're forever forgetting to put the cap back on the toothpaste.*

Comment: As the lecture notes say, this is *often* how the progressive is used, but it's not an absolute rule. The context usually makes it clear why you're using _always_ for emphasis.

Comment: why doesn't someone put one of these as an Answer?

Answer (score 1):

"In present-day English combinations of the progressive and adverbials of frequency often convey connotations of annoyance or irritation... See page 19 [here](http://clu.uni.no/icame/ij18/elsness.pdf) [Tim Romano]"

In American English, a great amount of time followed with -ing or a continuum , often presents annoyance, exaggeration,complaints or irritation.

For example:

> -You're always using the word like.
>
> -You're forever forgetting to emphasize the swells.
>
> -That dog forever barks when I get close.
>
> -Why does she always look at me like that?

This is often how the progressive is used, but it's not a definite rule. The context usually makes it clear why you're using always for emphasis.

Comment: He's _always_ helping neighbours with their odd jobs. (Mind you. it could be the missus complaining that he prioritises wrongly;))